# Payment jQuery plugin validate date month

Tags: jquery, validation, payment

I have jQuery plugin to validate credit card I want to to use separate fields to validate month and year I did year but I dont know to fix month

```
$.payment.validateCardMonthExpiry = function(month) {        
    var currentTime, expiry, _ref;
    if (typeof month === 'object' && 'month' in month) {
       _ref = month,
       month = _ref.month;
    }
    if (!(month)) {
       return false;
    }
    month = $.trim(month);
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(month)) {
       return false;
    }
    if (!(parseInt(month, 10) <= 12)) {
       return false;
    }
    expiry = new Date(month);
    currentTime = new Date;
    expiry.setMonth(expiry.getMonth() - 1);
    expiry.setMonth(expiry.getMonth() + 1, 1);
    return expiry > currentTime;
};
```

then I've

```
$('#month-holder').toggleClass('invalid',
!$.payment.validateCardMonthExpiry($('#month-holder').val()));
```

and my field wont validate I mean is always not valid

```
<input type="text" name="month-holder" id="month-holder" 
class="input-txt width-65 cc-exp-mm" placeholder="MM" 
maxlength="2" pattern="\d*" x-autocompletetype="cc-exp-mm" required>
```

Comment: can you create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4gP2m/6/ here is link but there is lots of code

Comment: i just updated  
http://jsfiddle.net/4gP2m/6/

Comment: did you got any answer?

Comment: yes i have its simple
`expiry = new Date(month);    
currentTime = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;    
return expiry > currentTime;    `

Answer (score 1):

```
$.payment.validateCardMonthExpiry = function(month) {
var currentTime, expiry;
if (!month) {
        return false;
}
onth = $.trim(month);
if (!/^\d+$/.test(month)) {
        return false;
}
if (!(parseInt(month, 10) <= 12)) {
        return false;
}
expiry = new Date(month);
   currentTime = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;
   return expiry > currentTime;
};
```

This the answer